# Asymptotic variance of MLE of normal distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics, asymptotics, statistical-inference, estimation

I am trying to explicitly calculate (without using the theorem that the asymptotic variance of the MLE is equal to [CRLB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound)) the asymptotic variance of the MLE of variance of normal distribution, i.e.:
$$\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\hat{\mu})^2$$
I have found that:
$${\rm Var}(\hat{\sigma}^2)=\frac{2\sigma^4}{n}$$
and so the limiting variance is equal to $2\sigma^4$, but how to show that the limiting variance and asymptotic variance coincide in this case?

Comment: For starters, $$\hat\sigma^2 = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar X_i)^2. $$

Comment: Sorry for a stupid typo and thank you for letting me know, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

From the asymptotic normality of the MLE and linearity property of the Normal r.v
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}\left( \hat{\sigma}^2_n - \sigma^2 \right) \xrightarrow{D} \mathcal{N}\left(0, \ 2\sigma^4 \right) \\
\left( \hat{\sigma}^2_n - \sigma^2 \right) \xrightarrow{D} \mathcal{N}\left(0, \ \frac{2\sigma^4}{n} \right) \\
 \hat{\sigma}^2_n  \xrightarrow{D} \mathcal{N}\left(\sigma^2, \ \frac{2\sigma^4}{n} \right), && n\to \infty \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to do it without starting with asymptotic normality of the mle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following relation

$\text{Limiting Variance} \geq \text{Asymptotic Variance} \geq CRLB_{n=1}$

Now calculate the CRLB for $n=1$ (where n is the sample size), it'll be equal to ${2σ^4}$ which is the Limiting Variance. Therefore Asymptotic Variance also equals $2\sigma^4$.